# Angular CLI ejected App - pass parameters

Tags: angular, npm, webpack, angular-cli

I'm currently using @angular/cli@1.0.0-beta.32.3. I used the new eject feature to edit the webpack config. Now I'm confused how I'm able to pass parameters to my build.
For example: How would I do a 
`ng build --prod` or `ng test --code-coverage`?

How would I do those things with npm scripts.

Answer (score 2):

After ejecting, angular-cli disables the use of your ng-commands. It does however give you a basic setup for doing it yourself.

If you look into your package.json, you find the following:

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --port=4200",
    "build": "webpack",
    "test": "karma start ./karma.conf.js",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "protractor ./protractor.conf.js",
    "prepree2e": "npm start",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false --quiet" 
}
```

These are what the angular-cli folk have determined to be the minimum needed scripts to build your project from now on. They are run from your command-line, preceded by `npm run` or `yarn run`, depending on your preference.

So when you want to run a webpack build, in stead of running `ng build`, like you used to, you now run `npm run build`.

To build for production in webpack, you want to add a line to those scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --port=4200",
    "build": "webpack",
    "build:prod": "webpack -p",                        <-- add this line
    "test": "karma start ./karma.conf.js",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "protractor ./protractor.conf.js",
    "prepree2e": "npm start",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false --quiet" 
}
```

Now when you want to run a production build, just type `npm run build:prod` and webpack will run in production mode.

If you ejected with --prod, the above will not mean much will change, since I think webpack.config.js will automatically be put in production mode.

Some more info on what `webpack -p` does exactly, see https://webpack.js.org/guides/production-build/

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. But how would you execute Tests with coverage?

Comment: @Wortmann you need to add something like that: `"cover": "karma start ./karma.conf.js --code-coverage"`, then execute it `npm run cover` or maybe even `ng cover`. Not tested, just the idea.